# How to display timer in Python app and load images in chronological order

Tags: python

I am working in Python and I was wondering how could I make it so the image loaded is in order of date created as opposed to being randomly loaded via "`*img = pyglet.image.load(random.choice(image_paths))*`". Furthermore I wanted to display a persistent timer in seconds which counts down to the next image (and plays a sound at the 0 second mark).

Thanks in advance

```
import argparse
import random
import os

import pyglet


def update_pan_zoom_speeds():
    global _pan_speed_x
    global _pan_speed_y
    global _zoom_speed
    _pan_speed_x = random.randint(-8, 8)
    _pan_speed_y = random.randint(-8, 8)
    _zoom_speed = random.uniform(-0.02, 0.02)
    return _pan_speed_x, _pan_speed_y, _zoom_speed


def update_pan(dt):
    sprite.x += dt * _pan_speed_x
    sprite.y += dt * _pan_speed_y


def update_zoom(dt):
    sprite.scale += dt * _zoom_speed


def update_image(dt):
    img = pyglet.image.load(random.choice(image_paths))
    sprite.image = img
    sprite.scale = get_scale(window, img)
    sprite.x = 0
    sprite.y = 0
    update_pan_zoom_speeds()
    window.clear()


def get_image_paths(input_dir='.'):
    paths = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_dir, topdown=True):
        for file in sorted(files):
            if file.endswith(('jpg', 'png', 'gif')):
                path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, file))
                paths.append(path)
    return paths


def get_scale(window, image):
    if image.width > image.height:
        scale = float(window.width) / image.width
    else:
        scale = float(window.height) / image.height
    return scale


window = pyglet.window.Window(fullscreen=True)


@window.event
def on_draw():
    sprite.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _pan_speed_x, _pan_speed_y, _zoom_speed = update_pan_zoom_speeds()

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('dir', help='directory of images',
                        nargs='?', default=os.getcwd())
    args = parser.parse_args()

    image_paths = get_image_paths(args.dir)
    img = pyglet.image.load(random.choice(image_paths))
    sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img)
    sprite.scale = get_scale(window, img)

    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update_image, 6.0)
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update_pan, 1/60.0)
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update_zoom, 1/60.0)

    pyglet.app.run()
```

Unable to load based off the date modified attribute, it keeps loading randomly, timer is also non-functional.